# Read from certain letter to end

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I want to read a string from the character "," to the very end.
I think this is either doable with sed or with awk any ideas?

Example:

```
socialcoding,github.html
```

I want him to echo only github

Comment: Only github and not github.html?? First answer is based on github.html and second is for github. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` you can do the following.

```
awk -F"," '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" "}' filename
```

#### Update:

Based on your question you want value after the `,` and not need the `.`.

If your example data is actual data then you can do this -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "socialcoding,github.html" | awk -F"[,.]" '{print $2}'
github
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo socialcoding,github.html | sed 's/.*,//'
github.html
```

I took "the very end" to mean "the very end" and not "until the dot" as your final sentence appears to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you want to split the string in two on ",",
then do:

```
echo socialcoding,github.html | cut -d, -f2
```

HTH Chris

Comment: This won't grab everything till the very end if there are more `,` delimited values.

Comment: Nevermind sorry about that. I am not clear in his question anyways. He wants everything after the `,` but does not need the extension.

Comment: `cut -f2-` gets the second and any following fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data stored in a variable, then you can do this:

```
line="socialcoding,github.html"
echo "${line#*,}"
```

prints:

```
github.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "socialcoding,github.html" | sed 's/^[^,]*,//'
github.html
```